# Should you rely on IF-statement catching any other integer value than 0 as true?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, if-statement

I'm writing a rather large project in Visual C++ and I was wondering if there was a way to clean up the error checking code which currently looks like this:

```
// A header full of error codes like this
#define NO_ERROR            0x0000
#define CASUAL_ERROR        0x0001
#define ERROR_IN_THE_MATRIX 0x0015
```

-

```
// An example source file
int error;
error = openGLObj->Initialize();
if (!(error == NO_ERROR)
    return error;
```

As you can see, the error checking code takes a lot of screenspace when you have to write one after almost every function call.

So I experimented with something like this:

```
// Second example source file
int error;
error = fbxParser->ParseVertexData(...);
if (error)
    return error;
```

It seems to work at least in Visual C++ since I always return NO_ERROR (int 0) if there is no error and any other integer seems to set the boolean to true.

Is the latter a proper way to do things? Or will I run into problems later on and have to spend hours (again) converting my if statements?

Comment: "*A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`; any other value is converted to `true`.*"  -- C++ 11 Final Draft, § 4.12.

Comment: What you're doing is correct, don't worry.

Comment: What you are proposing is fine. However, I personally don't see it as much of a win on the readability front.

Comment: Using exceptions is a nice way to avoid all of this... :-)

Comment: If screen space is your biggest worry, you could also do `if (!((error = openGLObj->Initialize) == NO_ERROR)) return error;` all in one line.  It's syntactically acceptable.  If I was coding, I'd actually leave it the way it was, though.  (Since error is an integer, I like to compare it as one.)  And the code I suggested tends to highlight the errorchecking more than the function.  You'd have to search harder to see what the code is actually doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is largely a matter of style and personal preference.

I personally dislike treating expressions that can have multiple meaningful non-zero values as conditions.  For example, I'd write:

if (ptr != NULL)

rather than

if (!ptr)

even though both mean exactly the same thing.  Conversely, if an expression *is* "logically" boolean (whether it's of type `bool` or not), I prefer to use it directly as a condition:

```
if (isdigit(foo))
```

rather than

```
if (isdigit(foo) != 0)
```

and:

```
bool cond;
// ...
if (cond)
// or
if (!cond)
```

and *not*

```
if (cond == true)
if (cond == false)
```

So in your case, I'd write:

```
if (error != NO_ERROR)
    return error;
```

(Note that I'm using the `!=` operator rather than applying `!` to the result of the `==` operator).

The explicit comparison gives the reader more context to understand what `error` is; you're comparing it to `NO_ERROR`, not to `0`, or `0.0`, or `NULL`, or `'\0'`.

If `error` were a purely boolean value, I'd write `if (error)`.

As I said, this is a matter of personal preference.  Given your definitions, this:

```
if (error)
```

is *exactly* equivalent to:

```
if (error != NO_ERROR)
```

and you can rely it it working as you expect. The condition in an `if` statement is implicitly converted to `bool`, which is essentially equivalent to comparing it for inequality to `0`.

So you don't have to worry about `if (error)` not behaving as you expect. Nor, with modern compilers, do you have to worry about the compiler generating less efficient code for either form.  Use whatever you find more readable. (Not writable; remember that code will be read many more times than it's written.)

Comment: I mostly agree with you, except for the bool variable. During later refactoring someone might decide to change the type of cond (for example when there is now a third state like "unknown"). In that case `cond == true` is likely to throw a justified warning while `if (cond)` might compile fine, although it might now be logically wrong.

Comment: @Philipp: I'm not sure why there would be a difference in warnings Both require a `static_cast<bool>(cond)`. And for those people who add a `operator bool` to `optional_bool`, well that's why the Standard comes in a hardcover edition.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, integers/floats in boolean context are interpreted as true, when they are non-zero. Pointers are interpreted as true, when they are not-NULL. But note that you can also write `(error != NO_ERROR)` instead of `!(error == NO_ERROR)`.

Often exceptions and RAII idiom can simplify error handling. They can be more effective than these syntactic changes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that NO_ERROR is always zero, What you're doing is fine.

Comment: "One register instead of two"?

Comment: Yes, instead of copying the 0 to one register, and the error to another and then comparing the two, you only test that the error register is not empty

Comment: It's wrong, there is not any difference between `if (x == 0)` and `if (x)`.

Comment: @Alon It's 2013. You can expect the compiler to do such trivial optimizations on its own.

Comment: Fine :) but once it was true

Comment: "One register instead of two" will only hold if absolutely no optimizations are enabled, which is rarely true.

Comment: I think it's not about optimization, always it will compile to one `jne` operation.